# How to connect Gradle to custom EXE and hook its console output?

Tags: c, gradle, splint

Although this question involves the C language, the [Gradle C Plugin](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html), and an *oldschool* C static analyzer called [splint](http://www.splint.org/), I believe this question can be answered by any Gradle guru who understands how to wire a Gradle build up to an executable process.

It's very simple: I have configured splint locally to analyze my simple C project's source code with the following command line:

```
splint +never-include -retvalint src/derpus/c/*.c
```

I am managing my project's build via Gradle (the C plugin), and would now like to invoke static analysis (splint) at the appropriate point in the build sequence (whatever that may be).

splint outputs to the console, and unfortunately no where else. And so I would like to see if I can "hook" this console output, check for certain keywords ("*error*", "*warning*", etc.) and fail/halt the build if splint complained about anything.

And so I'm trying to tackle several problems here:

- How to invoke splint from Gradle, and at the appropriate stage? For instance, whenever CodeNarc executes (after compile? after running tests?) is likely when splint should be invoked.
- How to pass the correct command-line args to splint with this invocation?
- How to hook splint's console output?
- How to fail the build when the console output contains certain keywords?

My best attempt thus far is:

```
task check(type:Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'C:/splint-3.1.1/bin/splint.exe', '+never-include', '-retvalint', 'src/derpus/c/*.c'
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    doLast {
        String output = standardOutput.toString()
        if(output.contains("error") || output.contains("")) {
            println "Chuggington!"
        } else {
            println "Meeska! Mooseka! Mickey Mouse! Output is: ${output}"
        }
    }
}
```

This produces:

```
Defining custom ▒check▒ task is deprecated when using standard lifecycle plugin has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 3.0
:checkSplint 3.1.1 --- 12 April 2003

Finished checking --- no warnings

Chuggington!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.327 secs
```

However I'm 100% confident my `workingDir` and `commandLine` args are incorrect, I'm not sure how I can fail/halt the build from inside that `if`-statement, and I'm not sure how to "position" this `check` task to occur before compilation and testing.

Any ideas, Gradle gurus?

Comment: `workingDir` is a directory where this tool should be run not where it's located. Typically it's project directory. When it comes to `commandLine` try: `commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'splint.exe', '+never-include', '-retvalint', 'src/derpus/c/*.c'`. You can omit assignment operator `=`.

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - please see the changes to my `check` task - I *believe* I correctly implemented all your recommendations. When I run `gradle check` I get the following error: `Could not find method +never-include() for arguments [-retvalint] on task ':check'.` (1) **Any ideas?** And (2) What about actually failing/halting the build when I want to? Thanks again!

Comment: There're nor commas between list arguments. All command arguments should be separated with `,`.

Comment: Thanks again @Opal (+1) - I added the commas and still got an error, and realized it was because I had removed the `=` assignment operator in the `ext.output` closure. I added that back in and it is now building successfully (see the update above). The output I am seeing is normal `splint` output, **however** I was surprised that my `ext.output` closure **did not** seem to execute, as I should be seeing the Mickey Mouse statement being printed somewhere. Any ideas as to why `ext.output` didn't execute? Thanks again for all your help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`workingDir` is a directory where this tool should be run not where it's located. Typically it's project directory. When it comes to commandLine try:

```
commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'splint.exe', '+never-include', '-retvalint', 'src/derpus/c/*.c'
```

In command above all the arguments should be separated with a comma: `,`.

You can omit assignment operator `=`.

When it comes to *parsing* output - it doesn't work because in the closure it's not generated yet. Try:

```
standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

doLast {
    String output = standardOutput.toString()
    if(output.contains("error") || output.contains("")) {
        println "Chuggington!"
    } else {
        println "Meeska! Mooseka! Mickey Mouse!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - however when I added your changes I get `> Cannot get property 'splintOutput' on extra properties extension as it does not exist`. Thoughts?

Comment: Try updated answer - it should be declared inside `check` task block.

Comment: Thanks again so much @Opal (+1) - we're so close. Please see my updated `check` task and respective output. It is now printing (thank you), however it is not printing the expected Mickey Mouse message. Instead it is printing `Chugginton!` because `output` is an empty string. As you can see from the build output, the output should **not** be empty (for instance it contaiins the string `Finished checking --- no warnings` amongst other things). Any ideas as to what is still wrong? Thanks again *enormously*!

Comment: @smeeb It's quite difficult to help now since I can't reproduce it, *but* check also the `standardError` stream - is it empty as well? It may be also possible that you need to use `exec` in the following way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093223/how-to-use-exec-output-in-gradle (`new ByteArrayOutputSteram().with { os -> ...}`)

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - `> No such property: standardError for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec_Decorated` - are you sure that exists?

Comment: Sorry, should be `errorOutput` - see the docs: https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html . If it doesn't help - apply the solution provided in link in previous comment.

Comment: OK @Opal (+1) - thank you! That did the trick. Any ideas about failing the build if an actual error shows up in `STDERR`?

Comment: @smeeb, just throw a `GradleException` with an appropriate message. If I helped you, please accept the answer.