# Update dependencies in Gradle only on wifi

Tags: gradle

Gradle can be used either online or offline.

I am looking for way, to "tell" gradle, to download newer dependencies only when on wifi.
In other words, if I am using slow mobile connection, I would like to defer update.
Sure, I could manually switch online/offline or test for newer versions myself when of wifi, but what I want is to gradle handle it automaticly.

I am sure it is possible, but how it should be approached?
Is there any plugin, that does this already? 
Or maybe gradle already offers this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to check if a certain network adapter is active. see the code [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34779295/745574) to get started. If you're able to identify which n/w adapter you're interested in, you need to check if it `isUp()` to determine if your wifi is connected. You'll end up with something like:

```
(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().find{it.someKey==someValue}).isUp()
```

The hard part then would be to tell gradle then to go offline. I don't think that is possible from inside a gradle script, but you should be able to put this check and the following line in init.gradle in your home directory, so everytime you invoke gradle this check is performed first.

```
startParameter.offline=true
```