# Run a command line with Gradle and Save the output result

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I want to run a command line with Gradle that this command has an output.
I run this command in windows powershell:
**./mybat.bat myArgs** when I hit enter, it will print some digit, like this:
**123456**
I want to run this command with gradle and save this result(123456)
here is some code that I written in android build.gradle file:

```
task getSomeOutput(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "${buildDir}/output"
    commandLine 'powershell', './mybat.bat' , 'foo'//this is myArgs for example
}
```

this works and prints the value 123456, but I want to save it in a variable, how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use exec() output in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093223/how-to-use-exec-output-in-gradle)

Comment: @swpalmer yes, but with a little difference :), thank you very much, this may be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the official doc [HERE](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)

This can be achieved with the following task

```
task executeCMD(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '.'
  commandLine 'mybat.bat', '>', 'log.txt'
     doLast {
         println "Executed!"
     }
 }
```

This will send the output of `mybat.bat`  execution and set the results into a txt file called log .

the `.` is the directory where you have the script .

in my case its a project root directory .

Answer (score 3):

the best approach I found is to add **'/c'** to commandLine arguments and use **standardOutput**, here some code that might help other people:

```
task getSomeOutput(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "${buildDir}/output"
    commandLine 'powershell', '/c', './mybat.bat' , 'foo'//this is myArgs for example
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    doLast {
        def result = standardOutput.toString()
        println "the result value is: $result"
    }    
}
```