# Create a gradle kotlin task to run command line and save output to file

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to publish the git commit hash to prometheus and for this I need to get the output of the following command and save to file.

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

I'd like to save to gitReleaseVersion.txt

I found some similar post for android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70720662/run-a-command-line-with-gradle-and-save-the-output-result) but I'm not able to translate it to kotlin gradle.

Here's what I have but it's not creating any file.

```
task<Exec>("getVersionInfo"){
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine("git rev-parse HEAD > gitReleaseVersion.txt")
        }
    }
}
```

Output: no error, no file

and also tried

```
task<Exec>("getVersionInfo"){
    val logFile = file("src/main/resources/gitReleaseVersion.txt")
    exec {
        commandLine("git rev-parse HEAD").standardOutput.to(logFile)
    }
}
```

Output:

> Cannot run program "git rev-parse HEAD" (in directory "/Users/kaigo/code/core/module/base/function-base"): error=2, No such file or directory

The file does exist and if I print the file path, the link resolves to the file.

Comment: Are you able to see the output printed to console? Most likely, you’ll have to assign a file writer to `standardOutput` for the output to be sent to a file

Comment: If I do a println("hello") I can see that, but I'm not able to save the output of the git command and print that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`exec {}`](https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#exec-groovy.lang.Closure-) runs an executable immediately. If you want to define an [Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:commandLine(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) task, then don't use `exec {}`, and instead configure your custom `getVersionInfo` task.

   Using `exec {}` can be good if you want to run multiple commands in a single Task, but here you're just using one.
2. the arguments need to be split up into a list, or (if it's available) use the `parseSpaceSeparatedArgs()` utility.
3. Piping the output to a file. Git will interpret `>` as its own arguments, and you'll get an error like `fatal: ambiguous argument '>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`.

   Instead, [capture the output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70317110/4161471) and write it to a file.
4. It's a good idea to register [task inputs and outputs](https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/incremental_build.html#sec:task_input_output_side_effects), so that Gradle is able to monitor tasks and avoid re-running them if nothing has changed.

After applying those updates, you'll get something like this:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.parseSpaceSeparatedArgs
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

val getVersionInfo by tasks.registering(Exec::class) {
  executable("git")
  args(parseSpaceSeparatedArgs("rev-parse HEAD"))
  // or manually pass a list
  //args("rev-parse", "HEAD")

  val gitReleaseVersionOutput = layout.projectDirectory.file("gitReleaseVersion.txt")
  outputs.file(gitReleaseVersionOutput)

  // capture the standard output
  standardOutput = ByteArrayOutputStream()

  doLast {
    // after the task has run save the standard output to the output file
    val capturedOutput = standardOutput.toString()
    gitReleaseVersionOutput.asFile.apply {
      parentFile.mkdirs()
      createNewFile()
      writeText(capturedOutput)
    }
  }
}
```

[Be aware that this implementation is not compatible with Configuration Cache](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16535), and will cause these errors:

```
> Task :getVersionInfo FAILED
bc00f347a22805f720fd975304b31335bd5fb665

2 problems were found storing the configuration cache.
- Task `:gitVersion` of type `org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec`: cannot deserialize object of type 'java.io.OutputStream' as these are not supported with the configuration cache.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:disallowed_types
- Task `:getVersionInfo` of type `org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec`: cannot serialize object of type 'java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream', a subtype of 'java.io.OutputStream', as these are not supported with the configuration cache.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:disallowed_types
```