# How to get windows domain name in gradle taks?

Tags: java, windows, gradle, build.gradle, system-properties

I am to switch between DB localhost or a dev server DB depending on the system I am running the code.

in the build.gradle

> System.getenv()

> System.getProperty("test.property")
> but this one comes as null.

2 possible solutions,
1) set the System varibale
2) Try some other way to get the domain

Appreciate your answers

Expecting a way to get the domain so that i can decide which DB and other scripts to be used.

Answer (score 0):

To read an env var in gradle,

- `var myvar = "$System.env.myvar"`
- `System.getenv("myvar")`

Also, try to avoid special characters such as `.` in env prop names.

If you really want to get the domain name, consider executing a windows command and store the output in a string.

> [How to use exec() output in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093223/how-to-use-exec-output-in-gradle)

Other options could be...

Creating `.local` file with no content, adding it to `.gitignore`, and then checking its existence.  It could be created in the local dev machines, but be missing from other places.

Adding something to the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file.  Because this is picked up on the local machine, you can test for it.  But, in other places where it is not set, you wouldn't see it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but the problem is System is getting as null.
Any thoughts?